# Retrieving values from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I have two tables: DPCWEB_PRODUCT and DETSVIEW_NAME. I want to select the PARENT_SPR_ID from DETSVIEW_NAME, but I need to select the DETSVIEW_NAME name from DPCWEB_PRODUCT. Right now I am doing this:

```
<cfquery DataSource="#REQUEST.DSN#" name="DETSVIEW_SEARCH">
        Select
           DETSVIEW_NAME
         From
           DPCWEB_PRODUCT
         Where
          PRODUCT_NAME = '#SESSION.SELECTED_PRODUCT_NAME#'
</cfquery>
<CFQUERY DataSource="#REQUEST.DSN#" Name="SPR_PARENT">
        SELECT
          PARENT_SPR_ID
        FROM
          #DETSVIEW_SEARCH.DETSVIEW_NAME#
         WHERE SPR_ID = #COMPLETION_FORM_SPRS.SPR_ID#    
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>#SPR_PARENT.PARENT_SPR_ID#</cfoutput>
```

is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you post the structure of the `DPCWEB_PRODUCT` and `DETSVIEW_NAME` tables? Not all the columns are needed - just the ones that are involved in the queries, plus any columns that define the relationship between the two queries. I think you can do this with one query but I'm not sure I'm reading the ColdFusion queries correctly.

Comment: Ed, there is no `DETSVIEW_NAME` table here - in CFML `#VAR#` is similar to PHP's `<? echo $var ?>` - i.e. the FROM part of the second query is the value of the column selected from the first query. (Which doesn't seem like a great database structure, but no idea if the OP has control over fixing that.)